# Set and update global values in the _layout view

Tags: asp.net-core, session-variables

I have an application which has a global setting - Enviromnet (not the build environment)

```
    enum Environment {
      TEST = 1,
      PREPROD = 2,
      PROD = 3
    }
```

I have placed a dropdown in the Navbar to make it accessible from all views. I would like the selection
stored in a Session var.

This is just to get the idea.

```
<select asp-for="@Session.Item["ENV"]" 
    asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Environment>()">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Please select</option>
</select>
```

I have been looking at partial views and viewComponents but I can't see
how they can solve my problem

How could this be solved ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax and call api on change of select option.